# Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UITextField'

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, swift4.2

With Swift 4.2, getting following error, that was working fine with Swift 4.

> Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UITextField'

Here is my error code.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: textField, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            loginAction.isEnabled = textField.text != ""
        }
```

Full Code:

```
@IBAction func alertWithLogin(){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Please Enter Credential", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    // ADD ACTIONS HANDLER
    let loginAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .default) { (_) in

        let loginTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        let passwordTextField = alertController.textFields![1] as UITextField

        // do something with after login
    }
    loginAction.isEnabled = false
    alertController.addAction(loginAction)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in
        // do something
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // ADD TEXT FIELDS
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
    }
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Password"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true

        // enable login button when password is entered
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: textField, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            loginAction.isEnabled = textField.text != ""
        }
    }

    // PRESENT
    present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`textDidChangeNotification` is a member of `UITextField` (and `UITextView`).

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShow(notification:)),
    name: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil)
```

Comment: I was coming here next :D It seems like they moved all the notifications to their respective classes.

Comment: Worked for me in Swift 4.2 Thanks Buddy!!

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem,

**Here is the simplest solution:**

Instead of using `forName: NSNotification.Name.UITextField.textDidChangeNotification`

Use like this in `forName:` Parameter:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: textField, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
//Your code goes here...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: textField, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            //...
    }
```

In swift sdk, All notification name should be the extension of struct: Notification.Name

So when use Notification.Name, you should ignore Class name(exc.UITextField), input "Notification.Name." then input some of your name(like "TextF") and use esc to show autocomplete

Comment: There is no such thing as `Notification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange` (at least as of Swift 4.2). Most notifications are *not* under `Notification.Name` (again, at least as of Swift 4.2).