# In a Swift UITextFieldDelegate how to trigger an action when the text is edited?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController which inherits from [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) and serves as the delegate for the text field in the view. I would like to trigger an action whenever the text is edited.

I tried implementing the `textField` method, which is listed in the [UITextFieldDelegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

The documentation describes this `textField` method as triggered when the text *should be* changed, which occurs *before* the specified text is changed. Here is the line from the documentation:

> Asks the delegate if the specified text should be changed.

As this `textField` method triggers *before* the text is changed rather than *after*, the text available at `textField.text` therefore contains the *prior* text, not the *new* text updated after the change. To access the new text, I would need to apply the `range` and `replacementString` parameters to `textField.text` to imitate how the text will be changed.

Is there an alternative to the `textField` method that is triggered not when the text *will be* changed, but instead when the text *has been* changed? I'm thinking that directly using the text after the change would prevent me from having to hack an imitation of the change beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Add a target with a selector for `valueChanged` and you'll be able to get the events like you need here.

```
// adding target
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .valueChanged)
// selector
@objc func textChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print(textField.text)
}
```

Comment: I placed the 'adding target' bit to where it's called in `viewDidLoad`, and added that `textChanged` function as a method to the ViewController. Build succeeds and `addTarget` is called -- but the `textChanged` function is not called when text is changed, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Make sure that you're adding it to the right `UITextField`. make sure that the `UITextField` `@IBOutlet` connection is not lost.

Comment: the action type should be `.editingChanged` instead of `.valueChanged`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried textDidChangeNotification? you will have to add observer for keyboarddidshow(notification).
For ur Ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52325593

Answer (score 1):

Just write extension UITextfieldDelegate to viewController, you will have these pre-defined functions:

```swift
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tweak to Frankenstein's version which works correctly:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func textChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.text)
}
```